# Downloading xml from the online URL using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am new to batch scripting process I  have a built in batch script which will download the xml file from the vendor URL but it is not creating in proper format. it was creating the partial file not an xml file. I am using the below in the batch script. but manaually I am able to download the file in right format only issue running from batch process

e:\vendor_apps\utilities\wget\wget.exe --user= --password= --directory-prefix="e:\vendor_apps\Prime\Worldcheck" --secure-protocol=auto --no-check-certificate --proxy=on https://www.world-check.com/dynamic-download/?lag=DAY&format=XML&subcategory=PEP

Comment: You've provided your working manual command, but you didn't provide the non-working batch script version. Please provide that. Additionally, I would generally try to steer you toward writing new scripts with Powershell, which has a built-in `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@echo off
set "password=password"
set "user=admin"
set "infile=https://www.world-check.com/dynamic-download/?lag=DAY^&format=XML^&subcategory=PEP"
set "outfile=test.xml"

>download.ps1 (
echo $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
echo $WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential^("%user%", "%password%"^)
echo $WebClient.DownloadFile^( "%infile%", "%outfile%" ^)
)

powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
powershell ./download.ps1
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope CurrentUser
del download.ps1
```

Note: this temporarily changes your executionpolicy from the default restricted to remotesigned. If your default is something else than restricted you should change it to that of course.

You also should still change password and admin to their actual values